# Core 2 error referencing Framework libraries

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a test project int Core 2 console (Core2ConsoleTest).

It make a reference to .NET Framework 4.6.1 Project (NetFrameworkTest).

NetFrameworkTest project references the standard System.Printer.dll.

[image: Core2ConsoleTest arquitecture]

[Download Core2ConsoleTest project here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArCJF44YRdJrlIRwR9mKFdgekDQsVg)

When I call to any System.Printer function I have the error: **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Printing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.**

I tested with other standard libraries like System.Windows.Forms.dll and the same error if the Core project references a Nuget Package that uses standard libraries.

Note: The same error with ASP.Net Core 2

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have the problem with ASP.Net Core Framework Project. I'm unable to create a new Project with Core 2.0 and reference a Framework library that references System.Printing.dll or other libraries.

But @mairaw gave me another way: On a project that works in Core 1.1, **updating the libraries Nuget to 2.0**, works correctly.

So it looks like a Visual Studio 2017 problem or Core templates.

My concern is to remove this functionality, because it allows to adopt the Core technology in a staggered way with a high code reuse.

**Edit: Added sample projects**

1. [CoreTest.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArCJF44YRdJrlIVAsYzYJQX_MJgyLA) -> A ASP.Net Core Framework Project created referencing Core 1.1 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 in the past, then upgraded to Core 2.0 using Nuget: **WORKS!**
2. [Core2Framework.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArCJF44YRdJrlIRYToKv5qzxXrq-JA) -> A similar project (ASP.Net Core Framework Project created referencing Core 2.0) created with Visual Studio 2017 15.3.4: ERROR when calling System.Prinig.dll from the .NET Framework 4.6.1 Project.

Comment: This is different than the example you provided (which targets `netcoreapp2.0` and is therefore not an asp.net core on .net framework app). Can you provide a similar repo for your problem?

Comment: I edited my answer to include two simple projects. Of course, with Core console apps isn't posible (or not), but in ASP.Net Core Framework it Works on Core 1.1 and Core 2.0 upgraded from 1.1, but no with a new Project created in Core 2.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work on .NET Core.

.NET Core 2.0 has a compatibility layer that allows loading and using .NET Framework libraries but this only works as long as this library only uses types and methods that are also available on .NET Core.

Since `System.Printing` is not part of .NET Core, this library will fail to access it with the exception you posted.

Only .NET Framework applications can use this API (e.g. an ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework application).

Comment: In Core 1.1 is allowed. I have a project that uses this type of architecture and it works. You know if this is a limitation that will be removed / resolved in future versions? This limitation creates a serious compatibility problem in my opinion.

Comment: `System.Printing` is a wrapper over a windows API in .NET Framework. Porting it to .NET Core would mean implementing a version that can use various printing systems on windows, linux and macOS, which I don't see on any roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Martin, but I'm talking about Core Framework on Windows with the appropriate .Net Framework installed, it does not require Linux or Mac, and above all remove a functionality that had implemented Core 1.1. I have an ASP.Net Core Framework application in production. What do I do with her? https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArCJF44YRdJrlIVAsYzYJQX_MJgyLA Related conversation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/packages?hubRefSrc=email&utm_source=lfemail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=lfnotification

Comment: Are you talking about .net core or asp.net core? Those are separate components.

Comment: I tested in both with the same result, but I need on "ASP.Net Core"